# Why does type casting from string to integer always return "0"?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm writing an AJAX chat script and I'm integrating a system to parse the time (basically like BBCode). The problem is, when I try casting the time (UNIX timestamp) to an integer for use with date(), it always returns "0". The code I am using to find and replace is below. I've also added a sample of what I'm trying to parse

```
$out = preg_replace("/\[time\](.*)\[\/time\]/i",date("c",(int)"$1",$out);
```

Sample:

```
<b>GtoXic</b>: [time]1342129366[/time]
```

Comment: Why not use `strtotime`?

Comment: From what I read, strtotime doesn't support UNIX timestamps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because what you are actually casting to an integer is the literal string `$1`, and converting a string to an integer works in the following way:

- If the start of the string is a valid numeric representation, use that until we come across a character incompatible with that format
- Otherwise return zero

In order to get this to work, you would use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("/#\[time\](.*)\[/time\]#i", function ($matches) {
  return date("c", $matches[1]);
}, $input);
```

The `(int)` cast is actually unnecessary, PHP will automatically handle this when you pass the value to a function that expects an integer.

Comment: Since you are using a anonymous function, it will only work with php 5.3+

Comment: @Besnik Fair point, but I hate providing `create_function()` based code cos it just feels so horrible. Of course in this case you could use the `e` modifier in the regex as well - but this feels equally horrible.

Comment: @DaveRandom yes, i agree that's horrible and to use an old version of php is horrible too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

The reason your script is failing is because `(int)"$1"` is in fact `0` (zero), so before it is passed as one of the arguments, it is already converted to zero.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with a callback function:

```
$out = "<b>GtoXic</b>: [time]1342129366[/time]";

$out = preg_replace_callback('/\[time\]([0-9]*)\[\/time\]/i', 'test', $out);

function test($matches)
{
  return date("c", (int)$matches[1]);
}
```